# Not able to update the data in more than one table in Asp .net MVC5

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Here I am able to add the data in more than one table. Let i have 3 tables User, Franchise and Fee.

I am not able to update the data in more than one table,it throwing the exception:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'User.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Franchise.UserId' on the other end.

Code:

```
public MessageResult SaveAndUpdateFranchisee(UserViewModel model)
        {
            var result = new MessageResult();
            try
            {
                User userData = new User();
                Franchise franchiseData = new Franchise(); 
                var ExistUser = db.Users.Where(a => a.Id == model.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                //Update record
                if (model.Id > 0)
                {
                    Fee feeData = new Fee
                    {
                        FranchiseeFee = model.FranchiseeFee,
                        PaymentTermsFranchiseFee = model.PaymentTermsFranchiseFee,
                        EquipmentCost = model.EquipmentCost,
                        PaymentTermsEquipmentCost = model.PaymentTermsEquipmentCost,
                        OtherFee = model.OtherFee,
                        PaymentTermsOtherFee = model.PaymentTermsOtherFee,
                        ConsumableStock = model.ConsumableStock,
                        PaymentTermsConsumableStock = model.PaymentTermsConsumableStock,
                        FrozenFoodStock = model.FrozenFoodStock,
                        PaymentTermsFrozenFoodStock = model.PaymentTermsFrozenFoodStock,
                        TotalAmountDue = model.TotalAmountDue,
                        TotalAmountPaid = model.TotalAmountPaid,
                        BalanceAmount = model.BalanceAmount,
                        LoyaltyFeePercentage = model.LoyaltyFeePercentage,
                        FixedMonthlyFee = model.FixedMonthlyFee,
                        Note = model.Note,
                        UserId = model.CurrentUserId,
                        LOIDocUrl = model.LOIDocUrl,
                        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now 
                    };
                    ExistUser.Email = model.Email;
                    //var pwd = SecutiryServices.EncodePasswordToBase64(model.Password);
                    //userData.Password = pwd;
                    ExistUser.Password = model.Password;
                    ExistUser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                    ExistUser.MiddleName = model.MiddleName;
                    ExistUser.LastName = model.LastName;
                    ExistUser.FullName = model.FullName;                    
                    ExistUser.MobileNo = model.MobileNo;
                    ExistUser.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;

                    franchiseData.Name = model.FullName;
                    franchiseData.MobileNo = model.MobileNo;
                    franchiseData.AlternateNo = model.AlternetNo;
                    franchiseData.CompanyPhoneNo = model.PhoneNo;

                    franchiseData.Address = model.Address;
                    franchiseData.City = model.City;
                    franchiseData.State = model.State;
                    franchiseData.PinCode = model.PinCode;

                    franchiseData.CompanyName = model.CompanyName;
                    franchiseData.CompanyAddress = model.CompanyAddress;
                    franchiseData.CompanyCity = model.CompanyCity;
                    franchiseData.CompanyState = model.CompanyState;
                    franchiseData.CompanyAddress = model.CompanyAddress;
                    franchiseData.CompanyPinCode = model.CompanyPinCode;
                    franchiseData.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    userData.Franchises.Add(franchiseData);
                    foreach (var item in userData.Franchises)
                    {                        
                        item.Fees.Add(feeData);
                    }
                    db.Users.Attach(userData);

                    db.Entry(userData).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    //db.Users.Add(userData);

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    result.Message = "Your franchise has been updated successfully..";
                    result.Status = true;
                }
                //For Insert recored..
                else
                {
                    Fee feeData = new Fee
                    {
                        FranchiseeFee = model.FranchiseeFee,
                        PaymentTermsFranchiseFee = model.PaymentTermsFranchiseFee,
                        EquipmentCost = model.EquipmentCost,
                        PaymentTermsEquipmentCost = model.PaymentTermsEquipmentCost,
                        OtherFee = model.OtherFee,
                        PaymentTermsOtherFee = model.PaymentTermsOtherFee,
                        ConsumableStock = model.ConsumableStock,
                        PaymentTermsConsumableStock = model.PaymentTermsConsumableStock,
                        FrozenFoodStock = model.FrozenFoodStock,
                        PaymentTermsFrozenFoodStock = model.PaymentTermsFrozenFoodStock,
                        TotalAmountDue = model.TotalAmountDue,
                        TotalAmountPaid = model.TotalAmountPaid,
                        BalanceAmount = model.BalanceAmount,
                        LoyaltyFeePercentage = model.LoyaltyFeePercentage,
                        FixedMonthlyFee = model.FixedMonthlyFee,
                        Note = model.Note,
                        UserId = model.CurrentUserId,
                        LOIDocUrl = model.LOIDocUrl,
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
                    };

                    userData.Email = model.Email;
                    //var pwd = SecutiryServices.EncodePasswordToBase64(model.Password);
                    //userData.Password = pwd;
                    userData.Password = model.Password;
                    userData.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                    userData.FullName = model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName;
                    userData.LastName = model.LastName;
                    userData.MobileNo = model.MobileNo;
                    userData.IsActive = true;
                    userData.IsDelete = false;                    
                    userData.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    userData.UserTypeId = 2;   

                    franchiseData.CompanyId = model.CurrentUserId;
                    franchiseData.Name = userData.FullName;
                    franchiseData.MobileNo = model.MobileNo;
                    franchiseData.AlternateNo = model.AlternetNo;
                    franchiseData.Address = model.Address;
                    franchiseData.City = model.City;
                    franchiseData.State = model.State;
                    franchiseData.PinCode = model.PinCode;
                    franchiseData.CompanyName = model.CompanyName;
                    franchiseData.CompanyPhoneNo = model.PhoneNo;
                    franchiseData.CompanyAddress = model.CompanyAddress;
                    franchiseData.CompanyCity = model.CompanyCity;
                    franchiseData.CompanyState = model.CompanyState;
                    franchiseData.CompanyAddress = model.CompanyAddress;
                    franchiseData.CompanyPinCode = model.CompanyPinCode;
                    franchiseData.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    franchiseData.IsActive = true;

                    userData.Franchises.Add(franchiseData);
                    foreach (var item in userData.Franchises)
                    {
                        item.Fees.Add(feeData);
                    }
                    db.Users.Add(userData);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //db.AddUserRole(userData.Id, 4);                  
                    result.Message = "Your franchisee has been created successfully..";
                    result.Status = true;
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Message = "We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later.";
                result.Status = false;
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? Are you using Database-first or Code-first? What is the `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` definition of the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is straightforward - your code is creating a new `Franchise` object but it never sets the `franchiseData.UserId` property.

Add this to your `franchiseData` population code before you call `db.SaveChanges()`:

```
franchiseData.UserId = model.CurrentUserId;
```

BTW, you should add code verify that the current user has permission to set foreign-key reference properties (like `UserId`) directly from values read from submitted forms because otherwise any user could enter `Id` values belonging to other users and gain access to information they shouldn't have access to - or otherwise alter with your database.